# React redux succinct way to remove object from array if match certain criteria and without mutating array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

React redux succinct way to remove object from array if match certain criteria and without mutating array

I have an array that contains a number of objects.

I am wondering what is the cleanest way to remove the items from the array if they match a certain criteria, while also preventing the mutation of the state as I am using redux.

The code below should work, but I am sure there must be a more succinct way, while also preventing the array being mutated.

```
state = [
     {
      name: 'larry',
      age 25
    },
    {
      name: 'zach',
      age: 20
    },
    {
      name: 'chuck',
      age: 17 {
        name: 'zach',
        age: 20
      }

]
```

**Redux reducer**

```
case 'REMOVE_LOGIN_ERROR_CONSOLE_MESSAGE':

  for (var i = 0; i < state.length; i++) {
    if (state[i].name = 'zach') {
      delete state[i];
    }
  }

  return [...state];
```

As I am using redux, I also want to avoid mutating the array.

Comment: Use `.map()` - create a new array with every object that doesn't have name `zach` and return it - that way the `state` array doesn't change

Comment: Today I learnt a new word _succinct_.

Comment: hahah @George i only learned it last week! :-) cant get enough of it

Comment: Can you tried?

`function findMatch(arr) { 
    if(arr.name === 'zach') {
        delete arr.name;
    }
}`

`console.log(array.find(findMatch));`

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, any way, this might be the solution you are looking for, return state.filter(item => item.name !== 'zach');

Comment: @DarrenSweeney cheers for this. strangely map doesnt work. I believe the reason is that `map` returns false. Filter does work however. Does this make sense to you?

Comment: map won't work in this condition, it just transforms the array, can't add or delete items. While filter will return new array except all the items not matching the condition.

Comment: @RaulRodriguez yup, my bad - mfahadi is correct

Comment: @mfahadi feel free to add as an answer. I am sure it will be helpful for somebody going forward

Comment: I can't, I guess the question is marked duplicate thats why

Comment: cant create a new question! only allowed once every 90 mins! thanks for your help anyway